# SQl - How can i create multiple copies of single table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-table

I have a table name 'RealData' and i wanted an exact copy of this table so i just did

```
Create table RealData_long as select * from RealData
```

Which worked well as i expected. Now i need to create multiple copies of the same table RealData. How can i create multiple copies of the same table? is it possible to do any modification to the above query to achieve this?Or do i have to write a new query?

Comment: You can create loop with vars in PL/SQL, don't think you can do otherwise

Comment: A loop as specified in the comment above otherwise you would just copy and paste that line over and over again

Comment: The real question is **why would you want to do this**. I can't think of any circumstances where multiple tables holding the exact same data can help with. 2 copies of the same table I can understand, and even that should be avoided if possible. but more then 2 seems to indicate a design flaw.

Comment: @Zohar Peled i just want to do 4 different kinds of calculation on the data i have in RealData and Then i need to modify the data in table.

Comment: Then run the same sql statement 4 times with different names.
You could have done this in less time then it took to write this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean to do what you're asking (no matter why and what for) - **dynamic SQL** may be the answer. *Generate* the query text, then execute it.